# Single Batch job performing heavy database reads

Tags: spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a Spring Batch solution which reads several tables in Oracle database, does some flattening and cleaning of data, and sends it to a Restful Api which is our BI platform. The Spring Batch breaks down this data in chunks by date and not by size. It may happen that on a particular day, one chunk could consist of million rows. We are running the complete end-to-end flow in the following way:

- Control-M sends a trigger to Load Balancer at a scheduled time
- Through Load Balancer request lands on to an instance of Spring Batch app
- Spring Batch reads data for that day in chunks from Oracle database
- Chunks are then sent to target API

My problems are:

1. The chunks can get heavier. If it contains of million rows then the instance's heap size increases and at one point chunks will get processed at trickling pace
2. One instance bears the load of entire batch processing

How can I distribute this processing across a group of instances? Is parallel processing achievable and if yes then how can I make sure that the same rows are not read by multiple instances (to avoid duplication)? Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a (locally or remotely) partitioned step where each worker step is assigned a distinct dataset. You can find more details and a code example in the documentation here:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/spring-batch-integration.html#remote-partitioning
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#partitioning-sample